# Fix neo4j performance in automated testing?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a test suite that clears out a neo4j database before every test. When I was running neo4j 2.1, everything worked great. But ever since I've upgraded to 2.3 (and still now with 3.0.3), I can't get my test suite to pass due to the fact that neo4j times out on random tests.

I only ever create 6-12 total nodes & relationships in a given test. This is the query I use to clear out the db:

```
MATCH (n)
DETACH DELETE n
RETURN 0
```

This is not necessarily the bottleneck, however; sometimes neo4j randomly times out on some other sophisticated queries.

By "timeout", I mean that each test is set to timeout at 5 seconds. A normal test takes anywhere from 0.2sec to 1.5sec. When neo4j randomly takes a long time for a query, it pushes over the 5sec limit.

Is there a reason neo4j has become less performant? Is there something I can do to fix this slowness? I am sending cypher over the REST API, if that makes any difference.